# Atualizar estado ao iniciar a mudar de página React

Tags: react

Eu estou pegando o nome da pessoa através do localstorage e passando pro estado pra mostrar em tela o problema é que quando eu mudo de página, Indo da página de login para home ele não mostra em tela diretamente já tentei como componentDidMount, mais só quando eu dou um f5 ele me aparecesse em tela, teria outra alternartiva além do componentDidMount e componentDidUpdate?

```html
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = { 
          firstname: '',
        };   
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const name = localStorage.getItem('@front-end/firstname');
        this.setState({ firstname: name });
    }

    out = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('@front-end/firstname');
        this.setState({ firstname: ''});
    }

    render() {
        document.title = "Home - VirtualBooks";

        return (
            <>
                <h1>Hello {this.state.firstname}</h1>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                <button onClick={this.out}>Sair</button>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Estranho a sua pergunta porque ao mesmo tempo tem um método que muda o estado para vazio ... é estranho ...

Comment: Eu chamo isso para apagar o localstorage, e assim esvaziar a variavel, a questao é como posso mostrar em tela quando eu entrar na pagina

Comment: Você não precisa esvaziar a variável ... parece que sua duvida é outra, e só está dando certo porque você está apertando F5 lógica e criado a variavel novamente ... tem algo a mais nas suas duvidas.

Comment: você tentou colocar o valor inicial desse state já com o valor do localStorage? Outra dica também é utilizar os hooks, fica bem mais simples do que usando classes.